# Kendoui Grid Get Selected Row Id when Edit Button is clicked

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a simple grid  and I'm having a lot of  trouble collecting the PersonID when the edit button is clicked using JQuery. I need the  PersonID because I'm going to add a file upload to the inline edit column and i want to upload a file and associate it with the PersonID. All help welcome :)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GridCustomPopupTemplate.Models.Person>().Name("Grid")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.PersonID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetPersons", "Home"))
        .Update(up => up.Action("UpdatePerson", "Home"))
)

.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.PersonID).Width(200);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
    columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit());
})

.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.Events(ev => ev.Edit("doOnRowSelect"))  
)



<script type="text/javascript">

function doOnRowSelect(e) {

     alert(The #PersonID# of the row which we are going to edit here....)

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I got this working by using the following JavaScript:

```
$("body").on("click", "[role='row']", function (e) {

    var grid = $("#Grid").getKendoGrid();
    var item = grid.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
    alert(item.PersonID);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `grid.dataitem` on the selected grid row.

```
var grid = $('#grdMyGrid').data('kendoGrid');
var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
```

**Updated with a OnChange(e) handler.**

In an `.OnChange(e=>e.OnChange("grdOnChange"))`, you can store and access the item. I am sure the grids change will fire edit button in another row is selected.

```
var selectedIndex=0;
function grdOnChange(e) {
   var selectedDataItem = e != null ? e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.select()) : null;

selectedIndex=selectedDataItem.MyModelID;
```

}

Comment: This doesn't work. The error says its unable to get the property 'value' of undefined or null reference.  Then if I add the following line to the grid
.Selectable()
The result is that selectedItem is null :(

Comment: If I change the grid to 
.Events(ev => ev.Edit("doOnRowSelect"))  
and click on the row (but not the edit button) ,I can get the PersonId. But I need to retrieve the id when the edit button is clicked. thanks for looking.