# Get row information of Edit button click of Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

To get row information of currently selected row we can do this

```
 var current = e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.select());
```

But how to get the same when i click on Edit button?

I tried `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(e.sender).closest("tr"));` it didnt work.

**EDIT**

I tried ways as suggested on the answers below, but its still giving me null. 
in the screenshot the commented code doesn't work either

[image]

**COMPLETE CODE**

```html
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="Scripts/KendoUI.js" type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
    { field: "id" },
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    { command: "edit" },
    { command: "list" }
  ],
            dataSource: {
                data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            "id": { type: "number" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            editable: "popup",
            toolbar: ["create"],
            dataBound: function (e) {

                //<input name="age" class="k-input k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value:age">
            },
            edit: function (e) {
                //This currentItem is null :( 
                var currentItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(e.sender).closest("tr"));


                if (!e.model.isNew()) {
                    $('.k-window-title').text("Newton Sheikh");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618607/kendoui-grid-get-selected-row-id-when-edit-button-is-clicked/31619887#31619887

Comment: what about e.target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `e.container` instead of `e.sender`, like this:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(e.container).closest("tr"))
```

**Update to make it work with a popup**

If you are using a popup editor, then the container will be the popup itself and the above will not work.

In that case, you can use the uid of the row to locate it within the table:

```
var row = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + e.model.uid + "']");
```

If you do not need a reference to the actual row, but only the data item, then you can simply use `e.model`. I have created a dojo with your code and if you check the console after you click "edit", you will see that there is no difference: http://dojo.telerik.com/iqAPO

Comment: You should include all of your code related to this grid. The screenshot is not enough.

Comment: OMG!!! SOLVED! THANKS A MILLION! was struggling for 2 days. it helped me solved two bugs at one go. 

var current = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(e.model.id); 

this code did it, :) thanks a million again..

Comment: I am glad it worked, but like I said earlier - you can simplify it even further: var current = e.model;

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `edit` function in the grid, you can access the data item attributes which is in edit mode using:

```
var grid = $("#yourGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: yourGridDatasource,        
    ...                
    edit: function (e) {
        var attribute = e.sender.dataItem(e.container).attributeName;
        // or simply
        var attribute2 = e.model.attributeName;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you include your grid definition in your question aswell?

Comment: My example would have worked fine (using `e.model` as suggested by @Orilux's edit)?!

Answer (score 0):

```
var gridDataById= $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");   
//Getting selected row
var selectedRow = gridDataById.dataItem(gridDataById.select());
console.log(selectedRow);
```

Comment: Please provide a short explanation of how this works and why it's a good solution to the problem. This makes the answer more useful to OP and future visitors.